# segmentation core dumped in my code for implementation of 'HUFFMAN CODING'

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the Huffman coding in c++, though the code editor is not showing me any error, when I try to run the program I am not getting the expected result, instead, it shows **Segmentation fault (core dumped) ...Program finished with exit code 139**

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    int freq;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

node *nodeData(int ch, int freq, node *l, node *r)
{
    node *huffmanNode = new node();
    huffmanNode->data = ch;
    huffmanNode->freq = freq;
    huffmanNode->left = l;
    huffmanNode->right = r;
    return huffmanNode;
}

class comp
{
public:
    bool operator()(node *l, node *r)
    {
        return l->freq > r->freq;
    }
};

//encoding funtion
void encodeChars(node *root, string str, unordered_map<int, string> &huffmancode)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;

    if (!root->left && !root->right)
        huffmancode[root->data] = str;

    encodeChars(root->left, str + "0", huffmancode);
    encodeChars(root->right, str + "1", huffmancode);
}

void calc_freq(int image[6][6])
{
    int arr[36];
    unordered_map<int, int> mp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            static int k = 0;
            arr[k] = image[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }

    //making a priority queue
    priority_queue<node *, vector<node *>, comp> pq;

    //pushing the elements in the pq
    for (auto pair : mp)
        pq.push(nodeData(pair.first, pair.second, nullptr, nullptr));

    //iterating till there is only 1 element left in the queue
    while (pq.size() != 1)
    {
        node *left = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        node *right = pq.top();
        pq.pop();

        int sum = left->freq + right->freq;
        pq.push(nodeData('$', sum, left, right));
    }

    node *root = pq.top();
    unordered_map<int, string> huffmanCode;
    encodeChars(root, "", huffmanCode);

    cout << "huffman codes are::" << endl;
    for (auto pair : huffmanCode)
    {
        cout << pair.first << "-->" << pair.second << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int image[6][6] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {0, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4},
        {1, 4, 3, 6, 1, 7},
        {0, 0, 2, 5, 6, 1},
        {4, 6, 7, 3, 6, 1}};

    calc_freq(image);
}
```

I want the final output to show the numbers which were entered in the image array and correseponding to them, their respective Huffman code

Comment: A core dump is a snapshot of your program at the moment it crashed. Try loading it in your debugger and see what was happening. Or, if you run your program from scratch in the debugger, it will stop when a segfault occurs and you can inspect it.

Comment: Your code crashes here for me: `node *left = pq.top();` because the queue is empty. `mp` is also empty which appears to be the only way the queue could be populated. Time to fire up that debugger.

Comment: If you are on linux, in case of segmentation fault, a tool like *valgrind* will directly give you the line which is responsible.